# Pretty new to poker, wondering how this hand wins

Tags: texas-hold-em, no-limit

Hand A: Ace of Spades, Jack of Hearts

Hand B: Four of Hearts, Four of Diamonds.

River: Eight of Diamonds, Seven of Hearts, Eight of Spades, Ten of Clubs, Ten of Spades.

Why does Hand A win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Texas Holdem, you combine your hole cards (the two you've been dealt) together with the five community cards, the "board", and make the best *five card* hand that you can. This is key - you can only choose up to five cards to make your hand.

The pair of fours that Hand B has been dealt is counterfeited by the board - that is, there are two higher pairs (two eights and two tens) on the board, so the best hand that player B can make is those two pairs (since a pair of fours is lower than either of those pairs) plus a kicker, used as a tie-breaker. Since the highest kicker player B can choose is the 7 on the board, player B's hand is just:

(Using the notation: s = spades, h = hearts, c = clubs, d = diamonds, T = ten, J = jack, Q = queen, K = king, A = ace.)

Ts, Tc, 8s, 8d, 7h

Since A has a higher kicker, the ace of spades (one of A's hole cards), player A's best hand is:

Ts, Tc, 8s, 8d, As

Since Ace is higher than 7, A wins because their kicker is higher.